# What does the writer mean by "green fatigues"?

Tags: meaning

I already know the expression *green envy* or *a green hand*, but this is the first time I heard of *green fatigues*:

> *Everyone stares at him briefly, at his congealed Wheatenea-and-lint carcass, but no one breaks stride; and who knows how long it will be before finally two policemen have to come in and hold their breath and scrape him out of the gloom and into the bosom of the law, from which he will emerge with **a set of green fatigues**, at least, and an honorable seat at night on the subway bench.*

(from the *Kandy-Kolored-Tangerine-Flake Streamline Baby*, by Thomas K. Wolfe)

Comment: A lot of [green fatigue](https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1053&bih=579&q=green+fatigues&oq=green+fatigue&gs_l=img.1.0.0i24l5.1128.1128.0.3163.1.1.0.0.0.0.233.233.2-1.1.0...0.0...1ac.NKyols63Cx8) pictures appear at google images, along with some irrelevancies.

Comment: You can do an image search on [Fidel Castro](https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1214&bih=850&q=fidel+castro&oq=fidel+castro&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2088.4412.0.4764.18.10.2.3.3.0.304.1522.0j2j4j1.7.0...0.0...1ac.1.vaFkgDZTLog), too, and get a lot of good examples.

Comment: Also, the author is usually referred to simply as Tom Wolfe.

Comment: I think this is General Reference. If I Google ["green fatigues"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22green+fatigues%22&oq=%22green+fatigues%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.2408&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I even get *pictures* of them without leaving the Google homepage.

Comment: I would say this since I answered the question, but I think that this is not GR in context.  Knowing that "green fatigues" *can* refer to a type of clothing does not rule out the possibility that there is also a figurative meaning, and the writer quoted is known for packing in the figurativity and the symbolism.

Comment: @Zack "fatigues are a type of clothing. ... commonly ... military uniforms" **is** GR. "*Green*" helps zero-in on the context.

Comment: @Kris: Not necessarily; I think Zack is right. For example, do the same query on "green thumbs" – what will that tell you? (I agree that the question might have been _better researched_; something like, "Is the author just talking about clothes, or is there some other figurative reference, such as in the expression 'green hand'?" would be an improvement.) But, given the references to _green hand_ and _green envy_ already in the question, and the various other figurative uses of the word ‘green’ (e.g., _green energy_, ) I think this is a fair question, and I wouldn't classify it as general ref.

Comment: Another pertinent point in the Gen Ref debate is that the O.P. did not ask, "What are green fatigues?" (which I'd be more inclined to call General Reference), but, "What does the writer mean by ‘green fatigues’?" (which seems to be a deeper question, because it focuses on that fact that something might be inferred, in addition to the color and style of the clothing. As @Zack points out, for example, this could mean prison, or it might mean a POW camp, or a totalian government.) The difference may be subtle, but I think it's significant.

Comment: @J.R. Your analysis is precisely what makes the question GR. Look at it this way, "What does the writer mean by ‘green fatigues’?" is squarely in the domain of litcrit (writersSE ?), not ELU. When the question is asked on ELU, it is scoped as 'what is the lexical meaning of?' not 'what is the imagery that the author is creating?'

Comment: @Kris: I respectfully disagree. Just because something is written in a book does not _ipso facto_ make it a better fit for Literature or Writing; it's still, at a fundamental level, language. An idiom in a book is still an idiom; the book simply provides more a concrete context for analysis. We may have to agree to disagree on this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, [*fatigues*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fatigues) are a type of clothing.  This word is most commonly used to refer to military uniforms that are everyday wear, as opposed to the "dress" uniform worn on formal occasions.  It can also be used for everyday-wear uniforms issued by other institutions; in this passage, I believe the writer is implying that this unfortunate soul will be issued a prison jumpsuit by the city jail.

"Green fatigues" simply indicates the color of the uniform; unlike your "green envy" and "green hand" examples, the color is *not* metaphorical.  (This *is* Tom Wolfe we are talking about here, your confusion is understandable.)  Someone who was familiar with the time and setting might recognize green as the uniform color used by a particular local jail or perhaps a short-term mental institution.